# I want to call a javascript function in a table td in php

Tags: javascript, php

I want to call a javascript function from a table td and pass this td value as parameter of this javascript function. this is my script and table.

```
<table width="100%" class="track">
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">Load Information</th>
                    </tr>                     
                    <tr>
                        <td>LOAD  DATE:</td>
                        <td id="ldate"><?php echo $datas[0]->DATE?> </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
<script>
       function formatDate(date_string) {
            var date = new Date(date_string);
            var monthNames = [
                "January", "February", "March",
                "April", "May", "June", "July",
                "August", "September", "October",
                "November", "December"
            ];
            var day = date.getDate();
            var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
            var year = date.getFullYear();

            if (day < 10) {
                day = '0' + day;
            }
            return  monthNames[monthIndex] + ' ' + day + ', ' + year ;
        } 
    </script>
```

I want to show a dateformat like MARCH 03,2016 ,but my actual format will show as 2016-03-03.

Comment: call formatDate function after document ready.

Comment: what is the problem then ?

Comment: At where you're calling the javascript function `formatDate`?

Comment: ok i use function after document.ready but how call this function in td.if i call this function like<?php echo formatDate($datas[0]->DATE)?> it shows this error        Fatal error: Call to undefined function formatDate() in /hsphere/local/home/c241023/sdff.dff/tracking.php on line 221

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `strtotime()` and `date()` using PHP:

```
$originalDate = "2010-03-21";
$newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($originalDate));
```